# Google cloud platform: named based conditions doesn't work

Tags: google-cloud-platform, conditional-statements, roles

According to this documentation:

[enter link description here](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/conditions-overview)

I can tell a role whether or not to apply based on an instance name. I tried all other conditions and they worked fine but hits one:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MJGiS.png)

When I try the whole expression it's not working:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rZ73O.png)

If I try only the resource.type part, it works. I need to configure this role to apply only if an instance name starts with something, but this functionality seems to be not supported, however.

Comment: The document says it is `Available for buckets that use uniform bucket-level access. If you cannot enable uniform bucket-level access, you can add conditions to the IAM policy for a higher-level resource, such as the project.` @vesselin

Comment: Thank you @ShabbirAhmad for your prompt reply. I went through this several times, but maybe I understood it in the wrong way? Please, correct me if I am wrong again. Does it mean that such resource name-based condition is not supported on project level? If yes, I am not even able to imagen how to restrict the access in the way I was told to. This is my scenario: 

We have few VMs each with auto generated name from a template. The first part of that name is alwasy the same and the second part is like a stamp.

Comment: So, to reduce the mistakes, we need to restrict a specific team to be able to delete those VMs, if their names start with this specific string.

Comment: You talk about "instance" and you paste an example of bucket filtering. I didn't catch what do you really want to do.

Comment: There are vm1 vm2 vm3 vm4 vm5-1 vm5-2 vmgreat vmnotgreat etc
User needs to has permissions to SSH vm1 vm2 vm3 vm4 and all vms, if there names starts with "vm5-". I am using:

COndition Tyme: Name
Operator: StartsWIth
Value: selflink taken from the vm Instance

Same rule worked for the first vm1,2,3,4 but not for the vm starts with vm5-> So now I am not even sure if it works because of the rule or it works anyway.